# how to store date coming from paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have date coming from paypal which is the payment_date and this date is formatted to this 07:39:49 Jul 05, 2013 PDT,how can insert this to my table. or how to insert only this Jul 05, 2013.. I am using PHP

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php 
$date="01:07:13 May 07, 2011 PDT"; 
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($date)); 
?>`

Try the above code

Comment: Thank you :)..what about the PDT ?is that possible?

Comment: I have given you the example of PDT!